# Isolating an object in Photoshop to paste in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transparency, background-removal, crop

I am trying to select an object out of a photo and place it in illustrator without a white background around it. I have selected the object, but if I try to paste it in illustrator it always sits within a white box. How can I make the background transparent and only place the object?

Comment: You might need to give a little more context as to the object you are trying to select and how you are going about selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

You Cannot Just copy and paste your Object for Photoshop to Illustrator in order to get Transparency It will create a white background behind your object.

To resolve this issue you first need to save you image in .PNG format With Transparency then import your layer in Illustrator this will give you the transparent background just like you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copy/paste, which does not bring in transparency, make sure your PSD file has a transparent background and only what you want showing is visible. Then from Illustrator you can File > Place the PSD image and the transparency will come through.